# Can't Locate Neo4j Community Edition

Tags: neo4j

The Community edition doesn't appear on the neo4j.com site.

The only download I can find is the Desktop version.

Is the Community edition no longer available?

Comment: https://neo4j.com/download-old/

Answer (score 5):

You can find non-Desktop versions of neo4j at https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/.

Answer (score 4):

You can find community edition at https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

You may not be aware that Neo4j Enterprise Edition is also free under the AGPL open source license.    There is really no reason you should be using community. I have a blog post coming out that shows why.  
 
 We compile Neo4j Enterprise from the official neo4j github repository for US federal agencies, but anyone can download and use it.   https://igovsol.com/downloads.html 
 I also wrote a blog post explaining why you can no longer get the free AGPL binaries from Neo4j Inc websites.   https://blog.igovsol.com/2017/11/14/Neo4j-330-is-out-but-where-are-the-open-source-enterprise-binaries.html

Comment: John - Thanks to you and @cybersam for the clarifications.  I was looking for the Community version in order to take an online class which is based on it.  If I understand correctly, I can achieve the same thing with the Desktop version.  Is the Desktop version the same as the Enterprise version?

Comment: You probably wouldn’t notice the difference between Neo4j Community and Neo4j Enterprise for your training. It will have some additional config options in the neo4j.conf file, etc.  <br /> <br /> I would just stick with Neo4j Community edition just so the available config options are the same as your training docs.   Re : Desktop tool - unless your training uses it, I would steer clear for a while. I am writing a blog post about why I think it may be a way to hook people into paid commercial packages.  Notice it comes with a Neo4j Enterprise ‘trial’ license.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @JohnMark I did not knew enterprise edition was free and open source till now. :)

Comment: If you want features like multi-database in Neo4j Community - check out the new DozerDB plugin for Neo4j.   https://dozerdb.org   https://github.com/dozerdb/